# Discord py Music bot gives error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I cant get my discord music bot to work, here is my code to run it. I am getting the error when i try to play music. please help

```
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music end or use the 'stop' command")
        return
    await ctx.send("Getting everything ready, playing audio soon")
    print("Someone wants to play music let me get that ready for them...")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    voice.volume = 100
    voice.is_playing()
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the error you're getting right now, but I do know it's either really hard or rather impossible to use YTDL in Python, since GitHub took it down. I'm surprised it's not throwing an error for that.

Comment: @AgentLoneStar007 If you have another way i could make a music bot that would be helpful

Comment: check the `voice` object, it looks like that is not getting set properly.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia It looks like it is getting set correctly, but im not sure of another way to set it

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the voice object not getting set properly because you are not passing any channel name/id to it. I think you should try this:

`voice = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=channel.name)`